# How to query entire table(3 tables with 100k records each) data and then display data from them in dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, common-table-expression

I have 3 models, Postgresql db -

```
##user.rb - :full_name
has_many :enquiries

##enquiry.rb - :actual_target_count, :actual_visit_count
##there are different types of enquiry too - business, formal, phone, email etc
belongs_to :user

##sales_projection.rb - :target_month, desired_target_count, desired_visit_count
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :enquiry
```

**Problem Statement** - If I have 500+ users who have provided a target for current month (july 2023) with different types of enquiries (60k entries), how can I get a projection of a particular month to show all the users desired vs actual targets.

Let me elaborate this in more detail below -

records in users table (500+ entries)

```
{id: 1, full_name: "mike"}
{id: 2, full_name: "jason"}
{id: 3, full_name: "remi"}
{id: 4, full_name: "sam"}
```

records in enquiries table (500+ entries), every enquiry can have multiple entries of users

mike has worked on 5 enquiries, mike has worked on 20 enquiries and so on....

```
{id: 1, user_id: 1, actual_target_coun:30, actual_visit_count: 40}
{id: 2, user_id: 1, actual_target_coun:10, actual_visit_count: 05}
{id: 3, user_id: 1, actual_target_coun:20, actual_visit_count: 10}
```

records in sales_projection table (50k+ entries), every sales_projection record every users projections (actual vs desired targets count) for selected month(here its july 2023).

```
{id: 1, user_id: 1, desired_target_coun:30, desired_visit_count: 40, target_month: "July 2023"}
{id: 2, user_id: 2, desired_target_coun:10, desired_visit_count: 05, target_month: "June 2023"}
{id: 3, user_id: 3, desired_target_coun:20, desired_visit_count: 10, target_month: "July 2023"}
{id: 4, user_id: 4, desired_target_coun:50, desired_visit_count: 15, target_month: "March 2023"}
```

Based on the above set of records, how can I show a list of all the users and their desired/actual count for a selected month?

this is what i want to be shown:

```
user   |   desired target  | actual target | desired visit | actual visit | target_month
```

This is not possible with ActiveRecord (which i have currently) as this will be very time consuming and increase the page load time.

Currently this is what I have:

```
##pseudo code :)
SalesProjection.where(target_month: "July 2023").order(target_month: :asc).group_by { |m| m.user.id }.map do |key, value|
{
 get user full name,
 get user desired count using joins
 get user actual count using joins

}

end
```

The above logic takes 1+ mins to load the execute.

What I have tried but need more help:

- Need help to try CTE ([common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)) as I havent tried it but still trying but failing.
- Direct way to write just one query with dynamic values to fetch and get the results in the desired output.

Comment: Downvoting without justification is not going to help

Comment: does the enquiries table have a month attribute? are you looking for the aggregated (sum) of actual_target_count and actual_visit_count for each user, for each month?

Comment: you are showing a field `enquiry_id` in the enquiries table. This looks like a typo, shouldn't the sales_projections have an `enquiry_id` field. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: enquires table only has created_at, I am able to use - where(created_at: Time.zone.parse(params[:month]).beginning_of_month..Time.zone.parse(params[:month]).end_of_month) to get the desired records of the month

Comment: Yes..thanks for the catch @LesNightingill, i have updated the description. both data of target of actuals vs desired are in different tables.

Comment: Thanks @LesNightingill, one more thing, what if I also have to check if enquiries.is_visited == true for visited counts and enquiry.is_qualified for qualified counts, how can I get that counts?

Comment: what do you mean? Are is_visited and is_qualified conditions for including the record in the output, or are they additional (boolean) values to be included in each row? Have you tried my query suggestion for performance?

Comment: Yes, I tried and wanted to check how can I modify the same to get different results based on two boolean columns...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query strategy is slow b/c you instantiate many ActiveRecord objects. The key is to instantiate only the objects and fields of interest, and only do it once. So here is how you might structure your query

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enquiries
  has_many :sales_projections # note: missing from OP

  def self.report
    select =<<-SEL
      users.full_name,
      sales_projections.target_month,
      sales_projections.desired_target_count,
      enquiries.actual_target_count,
      sales_projections.desired_visit_count,
      enquiries.actual_visit_count
    SEL
    User.
      select(select).
      joins(:enquiries, :sales_projections).
      where("sales_projections.target_month = ?", "July 2023").
      where("extract(month from enquiries.created_at)::integer = 7").
      where("extract(year from enquiries.created_at)::integer = 2023").
      where("enquiries.is_visited = ? and enquiries.is_qualified = ?", true, true).
      map do |u|
        [u.full_name,
         u.target_month,
         u.desired_target_count,
         u.actual_target_count,
         u.desired_visit_count,
         u.actual_visit_count]
    end
  end
end

User.report # => [["Olene", "July 2023", 82, 48, 80, 0],
#    ["Kalyn", "July 2023", 10, 2, 26, 0],
#    ["Drew", "July 2023", 7, 36, 53, 26],
#    ["Terry", "July 2023", 99, 26, 44, 37],
#    ["Olene", "July 2023", 82, 36, 80, 2],
#    ["Sherlene", "July 2023", 71, 19, 79, 43],
#    ["Delmer", "July 2023", 5, 48, 43, 20],
#    ["Connie", "July 2023", 86, 1, 42, 34],
#    ["Candis", "July 2023", 86, 17, 13, 9],
#    ["Candis", "July 2023", 86, 11, 13, 21], ...etc.
```

This should be much much faster than your query, I used 50 users, 5000 sales_projections, and 1000 enquiries and the query took 50mS. I didn't use any indexes... you should do that to get even better performance.

Rather than querying the enquiries.created_at as between two dates, I suggest performance will be improved by querying the month and year values directly.

I'll be curious to know how fast this performs with your data set.

Comment: OK I've updated the query with the new conditions that you mentioned.